# Find first and second td ONLY from table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to only manipulate those two TD's.  There are a ton of nested tables that are on very old code that cannot be changed.

the table has no class. but the main structure i can see is like this.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="nowrap" "bunch of inline stuff"></td>
    <td "bunch of inline stuff">
  </tr>
</table>
```

that is what I can see. the rest thats inside, i dont really care about but its all nested tables.

I want to be able to change all the "bunch of inline stuff" for ONLY those two td's but everything I seem to try runs all through the nested stuff.

any help would be appreciated. If you can tell me what I did wrong, that would be great too.

this is everything I have tried already

```
//$('#main_content_wrapper table:first tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').attr('width','240').attr('id','ezweb_lhr').css('background','lime');
//$("#main_content_wrapper table:first td:nth-child(1)").attr('width','240').attr('id','ezweb_lhr').css('background','lime');
//$("#main_content_wrapper table:first tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").attr('width','240').attr('id','ezweb_lhr').css('background','lime');
//$("#main_content_wrapper table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)").attr('width','680').attr('id','ezweb_content').css('padding-left','20px').css('background','red');
```

Comment: If you want to change the attributes for only two td's why don't you just a class to these elements.. That should be lot easier than hammering your way around.?

Comment: the problem with that @sushanthreddy is that there is a ton of inline stuff like width, height, etc that would override anything that would be in the css for that class

Comment: I tried your first couple of attempts and they select those `td`s just fine. Are you sure your `#main_content_wrapper table` part is finding the table you're looking for correctly?

Comment: the problem is that there are a ton of nested tables and it seems to cascade down.  it doesnt grab those first two and stop. @MalSu

Comment: @user450784 Because your `#main_content_wrapper table` selector grabs ALL the tables under `#main_content_wrapper`, independently of their level down the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$("#main_content_wrapper table:first").find("td")
```

this will give you an array of all elements which are td inside first table, which is inside element with id 'main_content_wrapper'. Using indexes you can find whether it is first or second. For eg, to access nth td element use

```
var nth_elem = $("#main_content_wrapper table:first").find("td")[n-1]
```

Remember ':nth-child' selector does not work in IE7 and IE8

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a reason to use find in this case, you could just add the td to the initial selector.

Comment: @MattWhipple adding onto the initial selector will make it slower.

Comment: @asawilliams, although i didn't know that will make it faster. Thanks for the info, :). Matt, to make it clear, i did like this.

Comment: Good to know, I'd assumed they were all written to be optimized equally.  I've also been using the context syntax over which find is apparently also preferable.

Comment: Hi @ParitoshSingh I dont get what you are saying.

Comment: @user450784 i said that you can first select element as i wrote. Now suppose you want to access first element then you should use following code.
var first_elem = $("#main_content_wrapper table:first").find("td")[0], where index is 0 i.e. [n-1]
where

Answer (score 1):

This will return all the `td's` in the first table:

```
$("main_content_wrapper table:first").find("tr:first").find('td');
```

Complete selection:

```
$("#main_content_wrapper table:first").find("tr:first").find('td')
    .attr({
        'width': '240',
        'id' : 'ezweb_1hr'
    }).css('background','lime');
```

Here is a working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYQej/)

Comment: As far as I know, jQuery processes those selectors, not IE.

Comment: Ya, then i may be wrong. but for css i am sure they don't work

Comment: in both scenarios the css stuff i am trying to add goes all the way through all the nested tables.  just not the first itteration of the td's

Comment: thats awesome @Phil but its the second TD that I am having the problem with.

Answer (score 0):

Basically used another piece that was unique in the second TD which was the inline width.  So for anyone else that might go through this, this is what i used.

```
$("#main_content_wrapper table:first tbody tr:first td[width='647']")
```